# Change order elements with CSS in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Figure 1 is the desktop mode; two images and text below, total three divs.

Figure 2 is how I want it to display in a mobile browser such as a phone.

[image: Expected result]

Any idea on how to make this happen?

I am open to any suggestions. The idea is for the text to show above the images to best illustrate the description of the two images. Placing the text on top in the desktop version is not an option.

Comment: do you have any code that you could show us maybe a jsfiddle

Answer (score 11):

You could achieve this by using CSS `@media` queries and flex [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/doyuqsmk/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div-1">
    <div class="div div-2">image 1</div>
    <div class="div div-3">image 2</div>
    <div class="text">my text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.div-1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #EEE;
    margin: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 660px) {
    .div-1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .div-2 {
        order: 2;
    }
    .div-3 {
        order: 3;
    }
    .text {
        width: 100%;
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

CSS Flexbox allows you to [change the order of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) without changing the HTML markup. So:

- Order the elements for desktop
- Then use media queries and flex display to change the order

```css
/* DESKTOP CSS */

#image1,
#image2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

/* MOBILE CSS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #caption {
    order: 1;
  }
  #image1 {
    display: block;
    order: 2;
  }
  #image2 {
    display: block;
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="image1">Image 1</div>
  <div id="image2">Image 2</div>
  <div id="caption">Caption</div>
</div>
```

Click "full page" button to view desktop version.

Comment: Thank you -- solved and greatful!