# how to order div in css with help of bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want layout like this [image]

desktop

|      1      |      2      |      3      |

tablet and mobile

|      2      |
|      1      |
|      3      |

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075983/how-to-use-particular-css-styles-based-on-screen-size-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use particular CSS styles based on screen size / device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075983/how-to-use-particular-css-styles-based-on-screen-size-device)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate of question linked above, because he also wants to change order of elements, that is not trivial. But that is also addressed in answers of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255240/change-order-elements-with-css-in-responsive-mode)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via JQuery Dom manipulation.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 480) {
        $("#one").insertAfter($("#two"));
    } else {
        $("#two").insertAfter($("#one"));
    }
});


<div class="row">
  <div id="one" class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div id="two" class="col-sm-4">2</div>
  <div id="three" class="col-sm-4">3</div>
</div>
```

Above jQuery code block will insert `div with id one`  after `div with id two` if window size goes below 480px so, div two will come on top and layout will be like `2,1,3`

Else it will arrange the divs as per the order like `1,2,3.`

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/gt8a3f7x/2/

Comment: can you collaborate with me  on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gt8a3f7x/#&togetherjs=tktGbx5mJt

Comment: i think you should join https://jsfiddle.net/gt8a3f7x/2/#&togetherjs=ypOsUwPElf then only i will understand how it how?

Comment: @SagarMistry see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993053/bootstrap-3-media-queries-tablet-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper div with class row, then inside put divs with classes col-md-12 col-lg-4
It will be 12 column width(full width) for medium and small screens, and for desctop it will be 4 column width(4 *3 = 12) 
Thats it!

Comment: You can implement it yourself, or watch on bootstrap website

Comment: Make shure you linked bootstrap css and js properly(on header). And maybe you need another wrapper for whole page, with class 'container'

Comment: i already added bootstrap links 
i tried javascript but i dont get what i wanted too

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are often flagged for deletion, so please make sure to add a little explanation. I realise that this works, but perhaps explain the -sm -md -xs breakpoint classes perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

1. Arrange the blocks as they should be on the mobile or tablet.
2. Use [offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) to change the order of the columns on a wide screen:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">2</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
```

Please check the result:

```css
/* Decorations */
.row.decorations > div {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 80px;
  padding-top: 6px; 
}
.row.decorations > div:nth-of-type(1) { background: #9c6; }
.row.decorations > div:nth-of-type(2) { background: #f93; }
.row.decorations > div:nth-of-type(3) { background: #69c; }

/* fix SO stick navigation ;) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { .row.decorations { margin-top: 75px; } }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row decorations">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```